# Twilio: Outputting the SID of a conference

Tags: ruby, twilio, twilio-twiml

When you dial a phone number through the Twilio API, the platform passes the call's unique 34 character SID to your application as a parameter.

For example, when the Twiml I send to the Twilio platform dials a call through a `< Dial >` verb, I can easily do:

> `puts params['CallSid']`
>
> `@incoming_Cid = params['CallSid']`

Thus, the Sid is saved as a variable for later use. However, I don't know what the name of the parameter passed to your application to find the `< Conference >` Sid is.

## Can anyone who knows please clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve info about a Conference by filtering the Conferences list endpoint by the Conference friendly name. For example if your Conference is named "foo" you can do

```
GET /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC.../Conferences?FriendlyName=foo
```

to retrieve a conference.

There is an example in Ruby here:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference#list-get-example-2

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldn't find a way to do this through Twiml responses.